# Can you access the window object of a remote page using nodeJs

Tags: node.js, scraper

I want to remotely access some informations located in the window object.

When I go to [this page](https://robertsspaceindustries.com/ship-specs), I can use the developer console to access window.RSI.ShipStatsApp in the console. Is it possible to access it remotely using nodeJs?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, no. But, of course, it's not really that simple.

You cannot access a programmatic object on another computer with Node.js anymore than you could with PHP or Java or any other programming language. Your programming environment (memory, CPU, etc.) is not the other computer's programming environment.

However, it is of course possible that the remote system allows access to its information via an API.

And you also might be able to get information by scraping the web site.

But basically, "access `window` object on this other website"? Not so much.